# Как считать ifstream сразу в std::vector<BYTE>

Tags: c++, оптимизация, c++14, файловый-ввод-вывод

Сейчас считываю поблочно файл в цикле *for*:

```
in->read((char*)(&tmpByte), sizeof(tmpByte));
vect.push_back(tmpByte);
```

Однако перед этим я сделал: `vect.reserve(n);`

Как видим - система скрупулезно считывает блок побайтам, после чего их пихаем в вектор.

А нельзя ли сразу считывать целиком блок?

И нельзя ли сразу считывать его в вектор?

P.S. Вдохновился статьей - [ClickMe](http://demin.ws/blog/russian/2009/02/08/reading-file-via-stl-iterators/)

Comment: tmpByte - char;

Comment: Вектор - std::vector<char> vect

Comment: `.insert` и `std::istream_iterator` в помощь.

Comment: 1. Сейчас Вы считываете данные не поблочно, а побайтово (раз tmpByte - это просто char). 2. Например, Вы можете использовать метод вектора `data()` для прямого доступа к области данных вектора. Естественно, лучше бы до считывания данных заранее знать объем считываемых данных (например, попросить у операционки размер файла) и изменить размер вектора соответствующим образом. Иначе, как я понимаю, огребете проблемы как с обычным массивом недостаточного размера. Ну и в `read()` тогда можно уже скармливать что-то типа: `in->read(vect.data(), vect.size());`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как поблочно но-то таким методом считывать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::ifstream file(fileAdrress, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> block;


block.resize(allocateSize); // Важно! data() не аллоцирует память.
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(block.data()), block.size());
if (!file) // EOF! прочитали только часть блока.
    block.resize( file.gcount() );
```

Спасибо, [**@Vladimir**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084049/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-ifstream-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B2-stdvectorbyte) и [**@Chorkov**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084618/stdvector-data-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-ifstream)