# std::vector.data(): использование в ifstream

Tags: c++, vector, c++14, ifstream

Как использовать vector.data() в ifstream?

```
std::ifstream file(fileAdrress, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> block;
```

Так?

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(block.data()), allocateSize);
```

Или как?

Comment: До этого с data() не работал, поэтому хочется уточнить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно, но есть тонкости:

```
std::ifstream file(fileAdrress, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::vector<unsigned char> block;


block.resize(allocateSize); // Важно! data() не аллоцирует память.
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(block.data()), allocateSize );
if(!file) // EOF! прочитали только часть блока.
    block.resize( file.gcount() );
```

Если смущает cast, то, смените хранимый в vector тип:

```
std::vector<char> block;
...
file.read( block.data(), block.size() );
...
```

Comment: а вы точно не ошиблись с первым вариантом?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan перепроверил. все правильно: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c431fcbe805c66e

Comment: Огромное спасибо